# Who gets paid on Diners, Drive-Ins, and Dives?

Tags: production, diners-driveins-dives

The show *Diners, Drive-ins, and Dives* features Guy Fieri going to various restaurants and eating there. Does any party get paid for this? Do the restaurants pay the show to get featured? Does the show pay the restaurants? Or does neither get paid and they just get free publicity?

Comment: Just out of curiosity...what prompted you to ask this question?  Have you been a fan of the show for a while?  Are you a fan of Guy Fieri?  I just ate at his restaurant in Vegas, so I am just curious.

Comment: @steelerfan I haven't watched the show for long, but my brother has. We are at a restaurant that was featured in the show (and has a framed poster signed by him in honor of that) and we were wondering if somebody got paid for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to an article in [The Twin Cities Business](http://tcbmag.com/Industries/Food/The-Diners-Drive-Ins-And-Dives-Effect), the restaurants do **NOT** get paid nor do **THEY PAY** to have their restaurants featured on the show.

The restaurants do receive free publicity and seem to have a vast increase in sales after the airing of the episode that features their restaurants.

> “They told us ‘We can do a lot for your sales., ” says says Ann Kim,
>   co-owner of Pizzeria Lola in Minneapolis, “‘We had no idea.”
>
> “They told us to get ready,” says Josh Thoma, founder of Smack Shack
>   in Minneapolis. “I was like, “ ‘I got it.’ I did not get it.”
>
> A month later, his sales and customer counts were up 500 percent.

The restaurants also do not get any type of budget or reimbursement for food that they prepare for the show for Guy Fieri to sample.

> Some use food with high ingredient costs and rapid spoilage. “I was
>   reluctant,” says Eric Goerdt, owner of Northern Waters Smokehaus in
>   Duluth. “I think it cost us nearly $15,000 in wasted product and costs
>   associated with cleaning” his specialized fish processing area after
>   the shoot.
>
> “I estimated about $12,000 in overall expense,” says Thoma. Then you
>   wait. It can be as long as a year until a DDD segment airs after
>   taping, but it’s always at least several months wondering if all the
>   effort will pay off.

[Guy Fieri](http://www.celebritynetworth.com/richest-celebrities/richest-celebrity-chefs/guy-fieri-net-worth/) has a net worth of $8.5 million due to the popularity of *Diners, Drive-Ins and Dives* along with his personal appearances, book sales, restaurant endeavours as well as several other Food Network shows that he is involved in.

Comment: I live near a DDD-featured restaurant, and the difference in traffic around it from when it opened to after the episode aired years ago now is still obvious.